# Leaflet height fullscreen fixed

Tags: leaflet

I was trying Leaflet, the display looks like Google Maps, but I find a lot of ways cannot meet my requirements. Is there any way in the web, the phone shows the following?

Bad display:

[image: Bad display.png]

The first time it is entered, it can be dragged to the outside of the screen.

Good display:

[image: Good display.png]

The first time it enters it is highly full-screen and cannot be dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-example) for initialising the map.  You can pass several options that will do what you want:

```
var world = new L.LatLngBounds([[90,-180],[-90,180]]);        

var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom:2,
    maxBounds: world,
    maxBoundsViscosity: 1,
}).setView([0,0], 0);
```

Setting `minZoom` stops users being able to zoom out so far that the top and bottom of the map are both visible (and overrides the zoom value passed to `setView()`).  You may need to calculate an appropriate value based on the height of the screen, and how much of the world it is useful to display in your application.  On its own, this still lets users pan off the edge of the map.

Setting `maxBounds` limits the view to a specific set of coordinates (the whole world in the example above). You also have to set `maxBoundsViscosity` to stop users being able to pan the map beyond these limits.

If you really don't want users to be able to pan the map at all, you can also set `dragging: false`.  This still lets you pan the map using the `.panTo()` method.